# Manage exit code in Makefile define

Tags: makefile

I am creating a target that can be used as a hook to add some extra procedure when is needed.

This is the code in the main Makefile

```
export MSG:="Linux hook"

linux-build:
@ echo "Dependency target"


linux-build-post: linux-build
    @ make -s -f linux.hook -q linux_build_post 2> /dev/null ; \
if [ $$? -le 1 ] ; then \
    echo "Target exist" ; \
    make -s -f linux.hook linux_build_post ; \
else  \
    echo "Target doesn't exist" ; \
fi
    @ touch $@
```

This is the code in the file linux.hook

```
linux_build_post:
    @ echo ${MSG}
```

This code works correctly, but now I am trying to create a template in the main Makefile. For example:

```
export MSG:="Linux hook"

linux-build:
    @ echo "Dependency target"

# Common hook target
# Parameters:
# 1: Target name
# 2: Dependecies
# 3: Hook name
define COMMON_HOOK_TARGET
$(1): $(2)
    make -s -f $(3).hook -q $(1) 2> /dev/null ; \
if [ $$? -le 1 ] ; then \
    echo "Target exist" ; \
    make -s -f $(3).hook $(1) ; \
else  \
    echo "Target doesn't exist" ; \
fi
    touch $(1)
endef

$(eval $(call COMMON_HOOK_TARGET,linux-build-post,linux-build))
```

But in this case the make command fails because `$$?` is replaced with the dependency `linux-build` then the if condition is evaluated like this `if [ linux-build -le 1 ]`.

Error reported: 
`/bin/sh: 1: [: Illegal number: linux-build`

How I can change the code in order to use `$$?` as the exit code of the previous command `make -s -f $(3).hook -q $(1) 2> /dev/null` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is actually this:

```
if [ $$$$? -le 1 ] ; ...
```

The call to `call` turns "$$$$" into "$$", then when Make executes the rule it converts "$$?" to "$?" and passes it to the shell.